# How can I format text to Title Case from within a transformation in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

Within a transformation in Kentico, I am trying to format text to title case. I have discovered CMS.Helpers.TextHelper.ToTitleCase() in some Kentico documentation but, I don't believe that is available from within a transformation. I was also hoping I could get access to a TextInfo.ToTitleCase() via one of the CultureInfo objects in Kentico (like CMS.Localization.LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()) but that doesn't seem to be available within the transformation either.

Any advice would really be appreciated.
[This is in a Kentico 11 website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what type of transformation you are using.  If you're using an ASCX transformation type, you can use the following:

```
CMS.Helpers.TextHelper.ToTitleCase(Eval<string>("ColumnName"))
```

If you're using a Text/HTML transformation type you would have to [create a custom macro method](https://docs.xperience.io/k11/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) to call that TextHelper method and return the title case value you're expecting.

Comment: this was a tremendous help. Thank you. It has been a while since I have worked with transformations.